# How to store reference to variable in another variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a system in Unity where i can make a list of variable references.

It's for a command system, and the idea is that if i type "ModVal set {some variable to change}" in my console, it will set that value to something new

This is in a game, where i have many variables I want supported by this, and these variables are store in various different scripts.

I could solve this by manually making switch statement cases to fit every variable I want to be supported by command:

```
string argument; //This is given by the player when command is typed, for example ModVal set player.health
int value;
switch(argument)
{
    case "player.health":
        playerController.health = value;
        break;
    case "a.second.variable":
        some.other.variable = value;
        break;
    case "a.third.variable":
        another.variable = value;
        break;
    default:
        Debug.Log("Variable not recognized");
}
```

But I don't want to do it in this manner, as  I would then have to manually add a new case for every variable that I want supported by this command.

Instead, I want to be able to define to arrays of equal length. The first of these string's should contain the string's that the player can pass as an argument of the "ModVal set" command, and the second should contain a list of references to variables

Something like this:

```
string argument;
int value;

string[] lookup = {"player.health", "a.second.variable", "a.third.variable"};
Variable[] variable {playerController.health, some.other.variable, another.variable}; //This would need to store a reference to the variable, not the value of it, as I need to change the root value, not a local variable equal to it.

int i = 0;
foreach(string str in lookup)
{
    if (argument == str)
    {
        variable[i] = some.value;
    }
    i++;
}
```

I don't even know if this is possible, but I surely hope so, seeing as C can utilize pointers, I feel like C# should have some way to do the same kind of thing. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!
If this is poorly articulated, feel free to inform me :)

Edit: Thanks to everyone who provided me with their help! I decided to make multiple dictionaries for "gamevalues" in a seperate script, that other scripts as well as the console can. I figured this would be cleaner than having many variables in various scripts anyway, but the information provided can surely be used elsewhere, and I am probably going to make a test script just to see if I can get it working. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Are you looking for the [Dictionary<TKey,TValue> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2). Usage: [tutorialsteacher](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-dictionary)

Comment: You need to implement a command management using Reflection. Obviously limiting the scope as to not modify anything anytime.

Comment: Never worked with Unity but it does sound like a dictionary will suffice, assuming Unity does not have something ready-made for this type of work already. Here is a [Unity specific tutorial on Dictionaries](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/lists-and-dictionaries#6356198fedbc2a0ee971437c), it seems that there are some caveats that you may want to look out for in unity if you proceed with using this

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see how dictionaries could solve my problem. I have reformulated my post to better describe my problem, I hope this clarifies things :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can get rid of modifications in your code while changing the list of supported variables without using reflection. However, using reflection in runtime is not a good idea.

The idea with the dictionary mentioned above is almost the same as your variant with switch-case. The main difference is that you will need to put lambdas to your dictionary in the beginning, and then your call will look like

```cs
// setup phase
_myDict.Add("some_command", (val) => { player.health = val; });

...
// calling
_myDict[command].Invoke(someFloatValue);
```

Your idea with the arrays is almost the same in case you will change values to lambdas (btw, it will not work without that).

If you still want to use reflection, take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue?view=netframework-2.0). However, as I already told you, it is not a good idea to use reflection somewhere outside the debug functionality.

Comment: Yes, I think that this is the solution. You should also mention the type of the dictionary: `Dictionary<string, Action<int>>`. You may also replace `int` by another appropriate type. But in any case this approach works only if the OP is setting variables of the same type. Otherwise we would need a `Dictionary<string, Action<object>>` and then add values by casting to the required type: `_myDict.Add("some_command", (val) => { player.health = (float)val; });`